# v-if not working with conditional rendering on Dropdown value changes

Tags: kendo-ui, vuejs2

I have implemented a Kendo DropDownlist as below:

```
<kendo-dropdownlist v-if="PaymentTypeList != null" 
    name='PayType' 
    class="form-control" 
    v-model="vModel.PayType" 
    :data-text-field="'Text'" 
    :data-value-field="'Id'" 
    :auto-bind="true"
    :data-source="PaymentTypeList">
</kendo-dropdownlist>
```

I have to render only one div below according the value selected on the dropdown list.

```
   <div v-if="vModel.PayType == PaymentTypes.Cash">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-3">
             <div class="form-group">
                <label>Pay Code
                <span class="text-red">*</span>
                </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="PayCode" name="PayCode" autocomplete="off" v-model="vModel.PayCode">
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
       <kendo-dropdownlist v-model="dropdownlistValue"
          :data-source="dataSourceArray"
          :data-text-field="'text'"
          :data-value-field="'value'">
       </kendo-dropdownlist>
    </div>
```

But the first div is never shown whatever is the condition either false or true.

When i try with the `v-show` it works.

How should i make this code able to work on `v-if`.

The plunker implementation is here on the link

https://plnkr.co/edit/Xbhm67KjnpovOWNBy2O2?p=preview

Edited: According to vue js

`v-if is also lazy: if the condition is false on initial render, it will not do anything - the conditional block won’t be rendered until the condition becomes true for the first time.`

But in my case when the initial condition is true the first `div` is rendered, and after that the first division is never rendered whatever will be the condition either true or false.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you solve this issue by using `v-show`. `v-if` is "better" suited for (not) rendering the DOM at all opposed to `v-show` that is just manipulating display of DOM (hidden/shown).

Forked your Plunker to this one: https://plnkr.co/edit/PjOhBbuTO6czxvQQ10da?p=preview (had to introduce "empty" select value).

Hope it helps...